# Parsing an xml that contains unknown number of values in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to parse an xml from an url,the xml is

```
<returnData>
    <authenticated>true</authenticated>
    <total>3</total>
    <managers>
       <email>rdpittman@wtabstract.com</email>
       <email>ms.daly@att.net</email>
       <email>caraw@wtabstract.com</email>
    </managers>
</returnData>
```

Actually I want to parse all the email addresses(it can be any number,here I have shown only three),the code I have tried so far

```
XElement loadedData = XElement.Parse(appData.strResponce);
 var data = (from query in loadedData.Descendants("managers")
                                select new LocalDB.RootObject
                                {
                                    manager_email = (string)query.Element("email")

                                }).ToList();
```

In the above code I am only able to get only the first email address.Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  `loadedData.Descendants("email")`

```
var data = loadedData.Descendants("email")
         .Select(e => new LocalDB.RootObject  { manager_email  = (string)e })
         .ToList();
```